# Restrict URL access in javascript server side

Tags: javascript

I have a website I'm building using Parse as the backend and I want to restrict access to particular URLs (technically URIs) to users that don't have administrator access. As of right now, when users try to log in, their password is checked against the hashed password in the server.

However, if I only want administrators to have access to http://mywebsite.com/secret.html and only once they've logged in, how I do that? Right now anyone can just go to that url, authenticated or not.

Edit: This site has no accounts other than the administrator ones. It's supposed to be anonymous.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer do you expect to get? check the username verify his being admin. End of story.

Comment: The standard user won't have a username since it's an anonymous service...so what's to prevent them from just going straight to the url? That's my question. How would I stop them from just straight up accessing the page?

Comment: @shadow — Because when the URL is requested, you check their auth/authz.

Comment: So do I just add an auth cookie or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant achieve this in a safe way with JavaScript or HTML because it is client-sided. You would be better off to use PHP for this or some other server-side web language.

with PHP you could easily do a login this way (on your login page):

```
if($_POST['username'] == "admin" && $_POST['password'] == "adminpass"){
    $_SESSION['authed'] = true;
}
```

And on all of your pages you wish to secure, use this on top of the file:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['authed']) || $_SESSION['authed'] != true){
    echo "You are not logged in";
    die(); //Kill the page so the secured content is not viewable
}else{
    echo "You are logged in";
}

// your secured content here
```

Comment: Ok cool. Guess I'm learning php today.

Comment: Although, I asked my professor and he said .htaccess was the way to go.